GCS Avro file into Bigquery in Dataflow
In GCP, Iam doing POC on dataflow jobs which reads AVRO in GCS and writes into BQ using the Google Datastreams_to_Bigquery template. These are the inputes files in AVRO format, not sure why getting the the Getting an "Error matching file spec"
"Error message from worker: java.io.IOException: Error matching file spec gs://<project_landing_bucket>/Sample_avro_file_directory/2/34301d970e15378452dc7dd22d2f298768dd4d_mysql-cdc-binlog_-1912936272_3_564926.avro: status ERROR
org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.matchSingleFileSpec(FileSystems.java:196)
com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.datastream.sources.DataStreamIO$ExtractGcsFile.process(DataStreamIO.java:314)
"Error message from worker: java.io.IOException: Error matching file spec gs://<project_landing_bucket>/Sample_avro_file_directory/3/34301d970e15329679786c7dd22d2f298768dd4d_mysql-cdc-binlog_-1912936272_5_590068.avro: status ERROR
org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.matchSingleFileSpec(FileSystems.java:196)
com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.datastream.sources.DataStreamIO$ExtractGcsFile.process(DataStreamIO.java:314)
I checked Input files, I could able to read this Avor files.
